# Amazon Product Advertising API - How I can fetch more than 100 results with ItemSearch?

Tags: api, amazon-web-services

does the ItemSearch operation have parameters like offset? I need to fetch more than 100 results, I don't mind if I have to execute more queries.

The parameters I use are the following:

```
'Service' => "AWSECommerceService",
'AssociateTag' => [TAG],
'AWSAccessKeyId' => [ID],
'Operation' => "ItemSearch",
'BrowseNode' => "2445220011",
'Condition' => "All",
'ItemPage' => $_GET["p"],
'Timestamp' => date("Y-m-d\TH:i:s.\\0\\0\\0\\Z"),
'ResponseGroup' => "ItemAttributes",
'SearchIndex' => "VideoGames"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the documentation:

> `ItemSearch` returns up to ten search results per page.
>
> The `ItemPage` parameter enables you to return a specified page of results. The maximum ItemPage number that can be returned is 10.

This is seemingly impossible, and your only option is likely to capture `MoreSearchResultsURL` out of the response:

> `MoreSearchResultsURL`: The URL where the complete search results are displayed. The URLs provided in the search results are the exact ones that you should use when you link back to Amazon.com. They are tagged with your Associate tag and contain other tracking information to increase your hourly request limit as the sales that you generate increase.

Source: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/ItemSearch.html

Comment: Well, you couldn't help Thunder, but "MoreSearchResultsURL" is exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: I hit a gotcha here...if you specify `ItemPage: 10` and there are only 9 results in their db, you will get nothing back. fyi.

Comment: Pretty common with any pagination system imo

Answer (score 8):

You can add parameters like MinPrice & MaxPrice and send your request in different price ranges to get more that 100 results. But still you end up having 100 products for that price range.

You can even add Keyword parameter i your request and can send different closely related values for this parameter.

Answer (score 0):

We can use Manufacturer parameter(Panasonic,Sony etc) to retrieve more results from specific category using Amazon Product Advertising API,

'Service' => "AWSECommerceService",

'AssociateTag' => [TAG],

'AWSAccessKeyId' => [ID],

'Operation' => "ItemSearch",

'BrowseNode' => "2445220011",

'Manufacturer' => "Panasonic",

'ItemPage' => $_GET["p"],

'Timestamp' => date("Y-m-d\TH:i:s.\0\0\0\Z"),

'ResponseGroup' => "Large",

'SearchIndex' => "Electronics"